# Passing Barcode to report.rdlc through parameter in .vb

Tags: vb.net

I have a barcode in PictureBox1 and I want to pass it over to the image in report.rdlc through parameters but since the barcode is not a typical image like .png, .jpg, etc. I am getting an error “value should not be null” but it works with .png image though.

Here’s my code:

```
Dim ms As New MemoryStream
        Form1.PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, Form1.PictureBox1.Image.RawFormat)
        Dim arrPic As Byte()
        arrPic = ms.ToArray
        Dim images As String = Convert.ToBase64String(arrPic)

    Dim param As IList(Of ReportParameter) = New List(Of ReportParameter)
    param.Add(New ReportParameter("Address", Form1.TextBox4.Text))
    param.Add(New ReportParameter("img", images, True))     
  ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(param)
   Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Comment: Details on the error?

Comment: Hi @Craig it says “Value cannot be null. Parameter name: encoder” But the barcode is the value although it’s an image though.

Comment: Have you tried debugging?  You should be able to see which item is unexpectedly null and which line this is occurring on.  That may help you figure out what is going wrong, or even if it doesn't, you can update your question with a little more detail.

Comment: You're currently passing what is in effect an encoded string rather than an image to the report, so the likely source of the problem is what you're doing inside that report to reconstitute it to an image.  Also notice you've enabled External Images, was it another plan may to save this image to disk, then load it again within the report?

Comment: Hi @Hursey, I will omit the “external images” thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add an image to your RDLC report and set the following properties of the image:

```
MIMEType <to your image's mime type> Ex image/png, image/jpeg, etc
Source = Database
Value = =System.Convert.FromBase64String(Parameters!img.Value)
```

Comment: Hi, still the same error. I tried an actual .png image, it passes the image to rdlc, but barcode does not it warns value cannot he null instead.

Comment: Try using System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.xxxxx instead of RAW. If you set your MIMEType in your report as image/png, you should use System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png here `Form1.PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)`. Also examine the contents of images variable. Make sure that it is not empty

Comment: It’s working with System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.PNG. Thank you so much, really appreciate it.